# NetSuite Subtotals on report

Tags: report, netsuite

I have a financial report that needs to group by a super category (custom) called brands and then underneath that also grouped by project name. One grouping was easy I can't seem to see how to do one more sub-grouping. Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the Brands as the first (left-most) column, and the Project next.  Then make sure you have the Group check-box checked under Brands and Group With Previous Column checked under Project.

[image: Settings on customization page]

Answer (score 0):

On reports you always need at least Columns To Group + 1 column.
ex. Brands, ProjectName, TotalAmount. if you have this last field available, click on ProjectName column, group tik will show.